# String Encode in C++

Tags: c++, encoding

I need to convert the string "Test €" to "Test &#8364 ;" and vice versa. Please make a note that its a string and not from the xml. For your information I am developing the application in C++ and using Xerces also for XML Parsing. Please help me how it can be achieved in c++ application.

Thanks,
Ram

Comment: Too broad. What have you tried? Did you write your own conversion method and it does not work? Are you trying to use some library and have problems with that?

Comment: I haven't write my own conversion methods and I can use some library to achieve that.

Comment: Possible Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154536/encode-decode-urls-in-c

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not a duplicate; this isn't asking about URL's...

Comment: How is the original string represented and encoded? And is it a srring literal in a source file, or is it read in from a text file, or does it come from keyboard input or something else?

Comment: Yes. Its not encoding the URL. Converting unicode characters to &#xxxx and vice versa.

Comment: User will key-in 100 &#8364 ; from the keyboard (command prompt) and need to store that into the database. If I change the value in the database to 200 € then it should be sent to the command prompt in the way that 200 &#8364 ;

Comment: Oh, sorry, it's called HTML encoding, not URL encoding, right?

Comment: yes. you are right Daniel

Comment: Whoa, you're using unicode to let users specify a currency type?

Comment: yes. This is will be received from some other application through tcp/ip protocol to my application. so the other application will send &#xxxx instead of unicode characters. In my app I need to encode it and store into the db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this answer may be platform-dependent, though I don't know for sure.

You can use stringstreams and casting. If `lookup` is a string holding the decimal version of the character code, this function will return the character version:

```
char fixchar(string lookup){
    stringstream converter (lookup);
    int i;
    converter >> dec >> i;
    return (char)i
```

(Note that for hex strings, which are prefixed with `#x` instead of `#`, you can just use `hex` instead of `dec`).

You can get the `lookup` strings by using the `find` function on the original string. Here's a loop that uses the above function to convert a string (called `fixd`) with `&#x[number]` substrings into a normal string with no character codes:

```
while (fixd.find("&#x")!=string::npos){
    tag = int(fixd.find("&#"));
    endtag = int(fixd.find(";"));
    fixd = fixd.substr(0,tag) + fixchar(fixd.substr(tag+3,endtag-tag-3)) + fixd.substr(endtag+1, fixd.length()-tag-4);
}
```

Similarly, you should be able to get the int version of a character just by casting it, after which you can do whatever you want with it, including adding it in decimal form to a string.

Comment: Thanks Kyle. I am testing this and let you know my result shortly.

Comment: Thanks and its working fine. I just changed fixchar() method to return back wchar_t instead of char. Also fixd is treated as wstring.