# Equivalent for .net Uri.EscapeDataString in CLI for unicode encoding

Tags: .net, visual-c++, unicode

In .net we have `Uri.EscapeDataString` which does encoding for unicodes.  It converts "Ää" to "%C3%84%C3%A4". What is the equivalent for `Uri.EscapeDataString` in CLI .  My code is in VC++ and i don't want to use Uri.EscapeDataString. I tried with `WideCharToMultiByte(...)`. But this is not returning same result. What is the API i can use in CLI or any other way is there to get the same results in CLI?

Comment: just so I'm clear: if you are using the CLI, why can't you just use the .NET version? Are you specifically after a non-.NET version of the same?

Comment: Yes... i am specifically looking for CLI version. I am not supposed to use .Net version in the current project.

Comment: maybe you're using a different meaning of "CLI" than the one I'm thinking of, because when I hear "CLI" I'm thinking "the .NET VM", so disallowing .NET would also essentially disallow CLI. Am I confused here?

Comment: @MarcGravell: What i mean by my comment is , i can get the out put as specified above by using Uri.EscapeDataString(..). But it comes under the library System.dll. But i am coding in VC++ and i m not supposed to use the System.dll in my project. So what else i can use to get the same result?

Comment: Look at this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154536/encode-decode-urls-in-c

Comment: CLI = Common Language Infrastructure.  CLI = Command Line Interface.  Avoid using "CLI" when asking questions about MSVC++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the answer with the help of my colleague. first convert widechar to multibye using WideCharToMultiByte(..). i.e convert unicode to utf-8. then byte by byte we have to encode it to hex.

```
string methodTOHex()
{
  string s = "Ä";


  int len;
  int slength = (int)s.length() + 1;
  len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, 0, 0); 
  wchar_t* buf = new wchar_t[len];
  MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, s.c_str(), slength, buf, len);
  std::wstring temp(buf);
  delete[] buf;
  LPCWSTR input = temp.c_str();

  int cbNeeded = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, input, -1, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
  if (cbNeeded > 0) {
    char *utf8 = new char[cbNeeded];
    if (WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, input, -1, utf8, cbNeeded, NULL, NULL) != 0) {
      for (char *p = utf8; *p; *p++) {
        char onehex[5];
        _snprintf(onehex, sizeof(onehex), "%%%02.2X", (unsigned char)*p);
        output += onehex;
      }
    }
    delete[] utf8;
  }

  return output;
}
```