# Conversion between utf-8 and unicode in web servers

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-8, webserver

I really want to know how web servers convert URL UTF-8 encoded characters to unicode.How do they solve problems such as duplicate URL encoding and non-shortest form utf-8 codes conversion such that explained [here](http://esupport.trendmicro.com/solution/en-us/1098016.aspx).

for example:
http://www.example.com/dir1/index.html?name=%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%B3%D9%85%D8%A7

to
http://www.example.com/dir1/index.html?name=الاسما

I wrote a c++ program that does this conversion but in general I want to know how web servers like apache or nginx do this.

Comment: I don't understand the question; UTF-8 is a specific encoding of Unicode.

Comment: Are you asking for code to convert UTF-8 to 32-bit "full" unicode, or something else?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encode/Decode URLs in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154536/encode-decode-urls-in-c)

Comment: @BoBTFish More correctly: UTF-8 is "transformation format" or an "encoding form" or "encoding scheme" of Unicode (which is the encoding).  (Just a question of vocabulary, of course.)

Comment: The example has nothing to do with UTF-8.  It looks more like a percent encoding issue.

Answer (score 1):

You meant doing something like this:

From - [Encode/Decode URLs in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154536/encode-decode-urls-in-c)

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;

string urlDecode(string &SRC) {
    string ret;
    char ch;
    int i, ii;
    for (i=0; i<SRC.length(); i++) {
        if (int(SRC[i])=='%') {
            sscanf(SRC.substr(i+1,2).c_str(), "%x", &ii);
            ch=static_cast<char>(ii);
            ret+=ch;
            i=i+2;
        } else {
            ret+=SRC[i];
        }
    }
    return (ret);
}

int main()
{
    string s = "http://www.example.com/dir1/index.html?name=%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%B3%D9%85%D8%A7";
    cout << urlDecode(s);
}
```

Comment: And what happens if the string is mal-formed?  And what is the magic number `37`?  And why the conversion _to_ in in the `if`?  And why isn't the argument type `std::string const&`, so that you can pass it a temporary?

Comment: magic number 37 is '%', i.e. if it finds a '%' sign it begins the conversion stuff

Comment: So why obfuscate with `37`?  Why not write `'%'`?

Comment: you're right sir. its just that when i found that function on the other page, i thought it wouldn't make much difference to leave 37 as it is. guess it does