# HTTP POST request - sending key value pairs - value contains '&'

Tags: http, post, parameters, request, uri

'&' is used as separator between key and value pairs.

But one of my value contains '&', how can I send this data?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to url encode it (most http related libraries have utility functions for doing so).

For example, key=&value will become key=%26value

You can find [more information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_reserved_characters) in Wikipedia.

> When a character from the reserved set (a "reserved character") has
>   special meaning (a "reserved purpose") in a certain context, and a URI
>   scheme says that it is necessary to use that character for some other
>   purpose, then the character must be percent-encoded. Percent-encoding
>   a reserved character involves converting the character to its
>   corresponding byte value in ASCII and then representing that value as
>   a pair of hexadecimal digits. The digits, preceded by a percent sign
>   ("%") which is used as an escape character, are then used in the URI
>   in place of the reserved character. (For a non-ASCII character, it is
>   typically converted to its byte sequence in UTF-8, and then each byte
>   value is represented as above.) The reserved character "/", for
>   example, if used in the "path" component of a URI, has the special
>   meaning of being a delimiter between path segments. If, according to a
>   given URI scheme, "/" needs to be in a path segment, then the three
>   characters "%2F" or "%2f" must be used in the segment instead of a raw
>   "/".

This question is probably a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622504/escaping-ampersand-in-url).

Comment: Thanks. My code is in C++, and I dont see standard function to do that. Please let me if there is one.

Comment: Answers to this question [1] should provide you some links to libraries [2] and code.  [1] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154536/encode-decode-urls-in-c [2] http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_escape.html

Comment: Other options can be to checkout the php code itself. You can peek the function php_url_encode and php_url_decode in ext/standard/url.c.