# Can I stop Visual Studio URL decoding Command Arguments in Debug mode?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging, win32-process

If I set my program to echo command arguments and run in Visual Studio debugger with Command Arguments "https%3a%2f%2fas" it will echo 'https://as'

However, if I run from the command line 'myprog.exe https%3a%2f%2fas' then it will echo 'https%3a%2f%2fas'

Why is it handling this differently, and how can I stop it? I have to pass in an argument that is URL encoded and it needs to not be interpreted by Visual Studio first.

Program is C++ and it's Visual Studio 2017 if that is any help.

Comment: Hi Andy, any update for this issue? If you've reported the issue to product team, you can share the link here, so that we can vote for it and follow it. And you can check if my workaround helps, just a reminder:)

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/630271/visual-studio-decodes-url-encoded-command-argument.html

Comment: I am going to implement a slight variant on fix 3 - add a parameter to say 'get arguments from a file' so I keep the ability to run from command line or debugger. This has the other advantage that I can keep the debugger arguments in source control.

Comment: Hi Andy, I checked the content from the link you shared. It seems this behavior is something like a built-in behavior by design. Sorry for the inconvenience it makes to you, my suggestion is that you can Go Help=>Send Feedback=>Provide a suggestion to report the latest two suggestions from your comment as a suggestion-format. `updated the document about Command-line argument page or add a feature to control URL decoding`.

Comment: The problem is even worse than this: Visual Studio will urldecode *any* command argument, including filenames. And it will *also* urldecode the starting directory, which obviously cannot be a URL ever. VS2019, but I cannot report the error anymore (out of support when I try).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I stop Visual Studio URL decoding Command Arguments in Debug mode?

Sorry but I'm afraid the answer is negative. This issue does exist after my test, and as far as I know there is no option in VS now can turn off or control this behavior. For this, I suggest you can `Go Help=>Send Feedback=>Report a problem in VS` to [report this issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/post.html?space=8) to product team.

> I have to pass in an argument that is URL encoded and it needs to not
>   be interpreted by Visual Studio first.

And since it works well in command-line. So what you need is to get the UrlEncode format string during the `VS debug process` in your development. For this you can try:

**1**.Add some code before where you need the real argument to UrlEncode the `argv[1]`(I think it's `https://as`). About how to do UrlEncode see [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154536/encode-decode-urls-in-c).

**2**.Set the argument in this way, set `https% 3a% 2f% 2fas`as the `argv[1]` instead of `https%3a%2f%2fas` in project properties, then add code to judge if it contains space, `if true`=>write code to remove the space in it and get a new string you want (`https%3a%2f%2fas`)

**3**.Configure your custom Argument file:

1# In vs, right-click the project=>add a Text.txt file into project.

2# Set the only argument in this as `Text.txt`.

[image]

Then the content of your Text.txt is the collection of your custom arguments.
For example:

In the line1 of Text.txt file is `https%3a%2f%2fas`, line2 is `test`, line3 is...

[image]

3# Then you can use code like this:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ifstream infile(argv[1]); //open the file

    string MyArgus[10]; //create my alternative argus
    MyArgus[0] = argv[0]; //let the first argu of Myargus=original vs argu[0]
    if (infile.is_open() && infile.good()) {
        cout << "File is open."<<endl;
        string line = "";

        int num = 1;
        while (getline(infile, line)) {
            MyArgus[num] = line;
            num++;
        }
    }
    else {
        cout << "Failed to open file..";
    }

    cout << MyArgus[0]<<endl; // projectName.exe always
    cout << MyArgus[1]<<endl; // https%3a%2f%2fas
    cout << MyArgus[2]<<endl; // test
    return 0;
}
```

So you can write arguments in this way in Text.txt file to set your custom arguments to avoid the auto UrlDecode in VS.

Hope it helps:)