# Can't identify files in VS2017

Tags: c, file, command-line-arguments, visual-studio-debugging

When I try to use an input file in command line, for some reason the program dont indentify to file.
It says in argc that it is still 1 and acts like it havnt got any file.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("%d\n",argc);
    return 0;
}
```

Like when I try to this code it print 1, but Igave an arguments of file so it need to print 2.
I put the command line arguments in Project->Properties->Debugging->Command Arguments->(file name)

edit:
here's a picture of my program and setting hope it will make things clearer.

[image]

Comment: Did you try calling on command line? How do you call your program?

Comment: How did you use an input file in command line? Can you share the step with us?

Comment: Besides, could you please share the error which  program did not identify to file with us?

Comment: How do you specify the input file in the command line? what is the exact command line you write.  It is impossible to guess what you can have written, so it is impossible to guess what you pretend.

Comment: Hi friend, any update for this issue? Can my answer make some help for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `input.txt` instead of `<input.exe`. And it would work to print 2.

About how to read the values within the `input.txt` file you can refer to [my post here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56845047/10910450).