# How to convert hex representation from URL (%) to std::string (chinese text)?

Tags: c++, string, hex

## Intro

I have some input that I need to convert to the correct Chinese characters but I think I'm stuck at the final number to string conversion. I have checked using [this hex to text converter online tool](http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/hexadecimal/) that `e6b9af` corresponds to the text `湯`.

## MWE

Here is a minimal example that I made to illustrate the problem. The input is `"%e6%b9%af"` (obtained from an URL somewhere else).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string attempt(std::string path)
{
  std::size_t i = path.find("%");
  while (i != std::string::npos)
  {
    std::string sub = path.substr(i, 9);
    sub.erase(i + 6, 1);
    sub.erase(i + 3, 1);
    sub.erase(i, 1);
    std::size_t s = std::stoul(sub, nullptr, 16);
    path.replace(i, 9, std::to_string(s));
    i = path.find("%");
  }
  return path;
}

int main()
{
  std::string input = "%E6%B9%AF";
  std::string goal = "湯";

  // convert input to goal
  input = attempt(input);
  
  std::cout << goal << " and " << input << (input == goal ? " are the same" : " are not the same") << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

## Output

`湯 and 15120815 are not the same`

## Expected output

`湯 and 湯 are the same`

## Additional question

Are all characters in foreign languages represented in 3 bytes or is that just for Chinese? Since my attempt assumes blocks of 3 bytes, is that a good assumption?

Comment: The bytes `E6 B9 AF` are the **UTF-8 encoding** of the character you posted here. A more correct implementation would undo the URL-encoding first, and then UTF-8 decode as necessary. If you are just going to output it to a processor that expects UTF-8, you only need to URL-decode. As for your last question, see ["The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets"](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Comment: You're using `to_string` to convert a number into the string representation in base 10.  What you _actually_ want is to convert that number into a single character.  Since you've converted it as a 2-digit hex value, it's guaranteed to be in the correct range, so just cast it to `char` and stick it in the string.

Comment: @Botje thank you for the suggestion and the good read :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your suggestions and changing an example from [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154536/encode-decode-urls-in-c). This is what I came up with.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

std::string decode_url(const std::string& path)
{
  std::stringstream decoded;
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < path.size(); i++)
  {
    if (path[i] != '%')
    {
      if (path[i] == '+')
        decoded << ' ';
      else
        decoded << path[i];
    }
    else
    {
      unsigned int j;
      sscanf(path.substr(i + 1, 2).c_str(), "%x", &j);
      decoded << static_cast<char>(j);
      i += 2;
    }
  }
  return decoded.str();
}

int main()
{
  std::string input = "%E6%B9%AF";
  std::string goal = "湯";

  // convert input to goal
  input = decode_url(input);

  std::cout << goal << " and " << input << (input == goal ? " are the same" : " are not the same") << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

## Output

`湯 and 湯 are the same`