# Windows api urlencode

Tags: windows, urlencode

String:
`Polo Perú Qatar 2022 - Mujer - Colección Fútbol`

I need obtain: `Polo+Per%C3%BA+Qatar+2022+-+Mujer+-+Colecci%C3%B3n+F%C3%BAtbol`

I need to get the urlencode in windows api or similar. Is there any way?

When I refer to **windows api** I mean functions similar to these

```
MessageBox( 0, "Test", "Title here", MB_OK )
GetSystemMetrics( SM_CXSCREEN )
ShellExecute( 0, "open", "c:\myfile.txt", 0, 0, 1 )
Beep( 1000, 250 )
```

and more...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Encode/Decode URLs in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154536/encode-decode-urls-in-c)

Comment: nop bro is different  :/

Comment: UrlEscape (from that answer) seems to be what you are looking for.