# Converting file path to URL with MFC

Tags: url, visual-c++, mfc, webview2

I have seen similar questions (e.g. [Encode/Decode URLs in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/154536/2287576)). But, for me:

```
CString strURL;
DWORD dwSize = _MAX_PATH;
if (InternetCanonicalizeUrl(strFile, strURL.GetBuffer(_MAX_PATH), &dwSize, ICU_BROWSER_MODE))
{
    // still has backslash
    AfxMessageBox(strURL);
}
strURL.ReleaseBuffer();

strURL = strFile;
strURL.Replace(L"\\", L"/");
strURL = L"file:///" + strURL;
AfxMessageBox(strURL);
```

Using `InternetCanonicalizeUrl` did not work:

1. The prefix was `file://` and not `file:///`.
2. The `\` was not replaced with `/`.

I did it manually and my version of the URL works with my subsequent [`WebView2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/working-with-local-content?tabs=win32cpp#navigate-to-a-file-url) function. To clarify, the path itself was built with `::GetTempPath()` and/or `::GetTempFileName()`.

Why did the built-in API call not do what I needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Why did the built-in API call not do what I needed?*

The best answer I can give to this "Why?" part of your question is that the "WinInet" library component of the WinAPI uses (or, at least, is *based on*) Internet Explorer internally … and we all know how dodgy and non-conformant IE can be.

However, the [documentation for the `InternetCanonicalizeUrl` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wininet/nf-wininet-internetcanonicalizeurla) does actually suggest (albeit cryptically) an alternative if you want a more complete/compliant result:

> In Internet Explorer 4.0 and later, `InternetCanonicalizeUrl` always
> functions as if the `ICU_BROWSER_MODE` flag is set. Client applications
> that must canonicalize the entire URL should use either
> `CoInternetParseUrl` (with the action `PARSE_CANONICALIZE` and the flag
> `URL_ESCAPE_UNSAFE`) or `UrlCanonicalize`.

I experimented with the latter alternative (it seemed the simpler of the two) and found a relatively trivial fix for your issue:

```cpp
//  if (InternetCanonicalizeUrl(strFile, strURL.GetBuffer(_MAX_PATH), &dwSize, ICU_BROWSER_MODE))
    if (UrlCanonicalize(strFile, strURL.GetBuffer(_MAX_PATH), &dwSize, 0) == S_OK)
    {
        AfxMessageBox(strURL);
    }
    strURL.ReleaseBuffer();
```

In the test I ran (using the path from `GetTempPath()`), this gives the full `file:///` prefix and replaces all backslashes with forward slashes.

(You will need to `#include <shlwapi.h>` somewhere in your code and will also need to include the "Shlwapi.lib" library when linking.)

---

On the use of three slashes after a `file:` prefix for "localhost" URLs, see [this Q/A on Super User](https://superuser.com/q/352133/1128872).

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for working code sample and explanations.