# Escaping html codes to plaintext format in QT

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QList of strings that contain portions of URLs that look like this:

`/search/?q=god%20of%20war%3A%20collection%20-%20playstation%203&suggestionV=2`.

I'm removing the `/search/?q=`, `&suggestionV=2` and `%20` portions with the `.replace()` function as so: `currentString.replace("/search/?q=", "").replace("&suggestionV=2", "").replace("%20", " ");` which results with: `"god of war%3A collection - playstation 3"`. How do I escape the html character codes found here: https://www.obkb.com/dcljr/charstxt.html in QT? I need to convert the %3A and other codes to the plaintext format so `%3A` gets converted to `:`.

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154536/encode-decode-urls-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP query strings have [two primary coding sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string):

1. A space is often encoded as a `+` character
2. Any character that carries a special meaning in an HTML query string is encoded by a `%` followed by two hexadecimal digits

Different browsers may or may not recognize different kinds of "special" characters that are subjet to `%`-prefixed hexadecimal encoding. Using simple search/replace to replace `%2A` with a `:`, and either `%20` or `+` with a space, and so on, is not reliable and is a flawed approach. Consider the following HTML query string:

```
%2520
```

You will discover that `%25` is the hexadecimal encoded character `%`, so after decoding it the string becomes `%20`. Are you then going to replace this with a space, leaving you with a single space character as the final, decoded string? Fail. The original encoded string was `%20`.

The only reliable way to decode HTTP query strings is algorithmically: scan the HTTP query string one character at a time, and upon encountering a `+` or a `%xx` replace it with the decoded character and then continue ***with the rest of the string***.